# How to use generics while subclassing collection class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, generics

For example I have a few classes:

```
@interface SomeModel : NSObject
@end

@interface SomeAnotherModel : NSObject
@property NSArray<SomeModel *> *modelsArray;
@end
```

What if I need to use NSArray subclass instead?

```
@interface SomeModel : NSObject
@property ArraySubclass<SomeModel *> *modelsArray;
@end
```

How to implement ArraySubclass to support generics like NSArray does?

Comment: take a look at http://drekka.ghost.io/objective-c-generics/ for example.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you'd declare one of your classes with generics suppport:

#### The .h file:

```
@interface ArrayLikeClass<ObjectType>: NSObject

    - (void)add:(ObjectType)obj;
    - (ObjectType)objectAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;

@end
```

#### The .m file

```
@implementation ArrayLikeClass

    - (void)add:(id)obj {
        // ...
    }

    - (id)objectAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
       // ...
    }

@end
```

You declare your class as generic, however in your implementation file you replace the generic arguments with `id`.